# How to validate when user upload a file that the file is a LESS file

Tags: php, jquery, css, less, validation

I use this file uploader to upload files: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

**I want to check the file that user uploaded is only LESS file** (I know how to check if the extension itself is *.less - **I want to validate the content**).

I saw this project:
https://github.com/agar/less.php
that parse LESS file, but I don't understand how it use it and how do I use this project (or any other project) to ask something like this:

```
isValidLESScode($text);  //True or False
```

Do I need to use less.js that appears on this page to do it http://lesscss.org/ ?
also - if I validate it is a LESS code, do I need to validate that there is no evil or viruses inside the code or the LESS validation covers that?

Comment: Your last statement makes it sound like that your goal is to scan for viruses. Is that the reason you are trying to validate the content or is the virus scanning a secondary goal?

Comment: My first goal is the scan for viruses (most important thing) - I wanted to know if I need to research about virus validation or that if I already validate that it is a LESS file - then it is free from viruses?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader) which unfortunately is not supported by all the latest browser versions ...

Comment: I don't think this is what I need since I don't need browser support - I want the file to be sent to the server and the server will validate the the file

Answer (score 0):

Server-side you can use less.js through node or one of the ports - PHP,c# or java. Are you using PHP otherwise?

In terms of viruses, less can contain JavaScript that is run during compilation but I don't think that happens if you use a port. Less can also generate CSS that has JavaScript that will run when used in ie. Lastly it is possible to write recursive less that makes the parsers give a stack overflow - there is a bug in less.js and dotless at least for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to check that the LESS file does not contain a virus, you can take a look at ClamAV.

To install ClamAV and use it within PHP, you need to install the clamavlib first by running  `apt-get install php5-clamavlib clamav clamav-freshclam` (or the equivalent commend in your package manager). Then, modify your php.ini file to load the ClamAV extension `clamav.so`.

You can take look at the clamav project http://php-clamav.sourceforge.net/ for function documentation. But it looks like the following code will scan the file for viruses and return a non-zero return code if detected.

```
if (cl_scanfile($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
{
    die('Found virus inside uploaded file');
}
```